# How to keep this keyword points to window object in webpack?

Tags: angularjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have convert AngularJS application to es6 using webpack and import/export syntax.

Everything works perfect except `this` keyword.

Since webpack wrap all my code during compilation into iife function (modules), the keyword `this` gets undefined in functions like:

```
.controller( …, function() {
 ...
 this.myFunc = function() {

  someFunction().then(function(data) {
   this.someVar = data;
   // this === window
  });

 });

});
```

In normal angular application without bundling this gets `window` Object.

I do not want to make a big changes except working with webpack (I have a lot of code places that have that). Is there any way to keep `this` to point `window` object in webpack?

Comment: You can use an arrow function instead: `someFunction().then(data => {
   this.someVar = data;
  });` . See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable) for details.

Comment: No, I don't want to change the entire code. just looking for settings to set this to window.

Comment: It is really bad practice to pollute the global namespace with variables. It leads to name collision that creates bugs that are difficult to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2):

Webpack does force code to use "strict mode". The problem comes from the use of ES6 `import` statements.

From the Docs:

> The static import statement is used to import bindings which are exported by another module. Imported modules are in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) whether you declare them as such or not.

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - import statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)